# Keycloak custom Docker ProtocolMapper deployment

Tags: java, docker, keycloak

I'm experimenting with keycloak and the integrated docker registry v2 auth. Everything is working fine with that. However, currently there is no real authorization layer and having a look at the sourcecode on github I can see that there is a class *AllowAllDockerProtocolMapper* which automatically grants all permissions for the docker registry to the logged-in user.

I'd like to implement a namespace based authorization mechanism, i.e. that the logged in user does only have push/pull permissions inside his own namespace (e.g. https://myregistry.local/username).

Right now, however I am struggling to get a simple working example up and running. I read the keycloak guide for spi at https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_providers and had a look at some examples on github but right now the deployed module does not seem to be picked up by keycloak.

What i did:

- Created class *UserNamespaceMapper* that extends *DockerAuthV2ProtocolMapper* and implements *DockerAuthV2AttributeMapper* (I basically copied the example from *AllowAllDockerProtocolMapper*)
- Created dirs META-INF/services on classpath and placed file there
  named *org.keycloak.protocol.ProtocolMapper* which contains the fully
  qualified name for my *UserNamespaceMapper* class
- Created a jar *docker-user-namespace-mapper.jar* out of my sourcecode
- Created a module, by executing the following command:

  `KEYCLOAK_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh --command="module add --name=a.b.c.d.docker-user-namespace-mapper --resources=/build/libs/docker-user-namespace-mapper.jar --dependencies=org.keycloak:keycloak-services,org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private,org.keycloak:keycloak-server-spi"`.
- Modified standalone.xml :

```
   <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:keycloak-server:1.1">
       <web-context>auth</web-context>
       <providers>
           <!-- THIS IS WHAT I ADDED -->
           <provider>module:a.b.c.d.docker-user-namespace-mapper</provider>
       </providers>
       ...
```

- Restarted keycloak

When i go to the Admin cli, and try to add a new mapper to a a docker-v2 client, the new mapper does not show up and everything seems to be the same as before the deployment. During deployment and server restart no errors are thrown. Can anybody help me to get this docker mapper correctly deployed?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Thanks,
-Ivan

Comment: Have you changed new provider ID?

Comment: Yes, i've changed the provider ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found out why it was not working.

The module was not picked up by Keycloak because I was editing the wrong config file. Instead of adding the provider to `standalone.xml` I had to add it to `standalone-ha.xml`. This is because I actually use the official Keycloak docker image [jboss/keycloak](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/) and having a look at their startup script `docker-entrypoint.sh` it becomes clear that `standalone-ha.xml` is used. You can find more information here :  [Keycloak SPI Providers and layers not loading when using Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57208709/keycloak-spi-providers-and-layers-not-loading-when-using-docker).

In case anybody is interested in how to implement/deploy a custom Keycloak mapper - based on user namespace -  for the DockerV2 registry: have a look my code here:
https://github.com/ieggel/DockerRegistryKeycloakUserNamespaceMapper

Cheers!